# Google Analytics with User ID - Can we filter to see which pages a user accessed

Tags: google-analytics

I wired Google Analytics to an internal app, trying to track user and pages.

The set up is working, I can see data on my User-Id Views.  However, I can't see the userId anywhere on this view.

I want to see a list of users who visited the site and which pages a user visited.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google analytics userID tracking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27059136/google-analytics-userid-tracking)